# How do I overlay text on top of a <a-plane> with AR.js and A-Frame?

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I am in a webAR project with AR.js and A-Frame and I am trying to overlay text on a plane or box, at first I thought the text was behind the plane but after I give an opacity of 0.5 to plane, I realized that the text is not really coexisting with the plane where the two intersect. What am I doing wrong?

Appreciate any help!

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd8uu.png)

My code:

```
<script src="js/aframe-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/aframe-ar-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

```
  <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded arjs='debugUIEnabled:false; sourceType:webcam; detectionMode: mono_and_matrix; matrixCodeType: 3x3; cameraParametersUrl: camera_para.dat; maxDetectionRate: 10;' renderer="logarithmicDepthBuffer: true; precision: high;">

    <a-assets>

        <a-mixin id="text"
            text="align: center; width: 3;
            font: https://cdn.aframe.io/fonts/Aileron-Semibold.fnt;
            value: Some text.">
        </a-mixin>

    </a-assets>

    <a-marker type="barcode" value="51" smooth="true" smoothCount="10" smoothTolerance="0.005" smoothThreshold="1">
        <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" position="0 0 0" material="opacity: 0.7" color="red"></a-plane>
        <a-text mixin="text" position="0 1 0" wrap-count="15" rotation="-90 0 0" color="blue"></a-text>
    </a-marker>

<a-light type="ambient" color="#fff"></a-light>
<a-light type="directional" color="#fff" intensity="0.3" position="-0.5 1 1"></a-light>

<a-entity camera></a-entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the plane and the text have the same z position (0). 
Change one of them to have a different(more or less than 0) z property.
You want to find out the location of the camera (in z). You can do this using the inspector (control alt I).
If the camera is positive z, make the text position a positive number.
If the camera is negative z, make the text pos a negative number.
Then they will not be on the same plane and will not be "z-fighting".